# What type of best bank account to store your savings in?

Tags: rate-of-return, savings-account

My wife has saved up quite a bit from a job that she had.  We put the money into a BoA savings account, but the returns are miserable.  What sort of savings account would you recommend to put these funds in?

I've heard of savings accounts with 8 percent annual returns, but I don't know where I can find them.

Comment: If by savings account you mean preferred stock or some type of 'bond', then sure, you'll find 8% no problem.  Not exactly a savings account though.  Countries that do offer 'savings' accounts with such high interest, usually mean massive inflation.  See this article, Mongolia was paying 15% interest with a 14.1% inflation rate in 2013.   http://www.marketwatch.com/story/6-bank-accounts-that-earn-over-10-interest-2013-08-07    Go to page 7, and see Argentina, an example with 22% interest and 25% inflation.  Savings = 3% loss per year.

Comment: Is that it?  I'll need to look into that.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

Savings accounts with 8% APY? Unheard of these days. You're lucky if you find one at 1%.

You should use checking and savings accounts only to hold an emergency fund (6 to 12 months of living expenses), or money that you will need in 2 years or so. The rest, invest in stocks and bonds.

Comment: At an intermediate level ofrisk/return, investigate CDs, money market backed accounts, and/or some of the "branchless" banks which have lower costs and thus can afford to pay somewhat better interest rates. Of a mix of any or all of these options, trading off liquidity, returns, and risk. It isn't an all or nothing decision.

Comment: Thanks for writing back.  The reason for that question is that I've heard of individuals saying that they put their money into some account when they made enough and lived off of the interest.  I figured that this was something that I simply never heard of before.

Comment: @gp443 Maybe a brokerage account, living off the returns of their investments, but not regular checking or savings accounts. The interest on those accounts is far too low to live off, and even if you have a lot of money to make that interest large enough, every year that money loses value with inflation, effectively making you lose more of it more and more.

Comment: @Yasmani, could you please tell me more anout how I can setup this brokerage account?  If you have a link to a company's site that would be great.

Comment: @gp443 I personally use Fidelity (http://fidelity.com). There are other brokers that are just as good: Vanguard (https://investor.vanguard.com/home/), TD Ameritrade (https://www.tdameritrade.com), just to name a few. Note that you would need hundreds of dollars to invest to be able to live from earnings alone. This is not a get rich over night kind of thing. And most importantly, you need to do tons of research on investing (which it sounds you don't know much about yet) before you put your money anywhere, or you risk losing a ton of it.

Comment: You probably meant "... would need hundreds of thousands of dollars to invest ..."

Comment: @dg99 Oops! You're right. I meant "Hundreds of thousands of dollars". LOL "Hundreds of dollars". Can you imagine?